# HTMLAgilityPack load AJAX content for scraping

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, winforms, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape a webpage using HTMLAgilityPack in a C# Web Forms project.

All the solutions Ive seen for doing this use a WebBrowser control. However, from what I can determine, this is only available in WinForms projects.

At present I'm calling the required page via this code:

```
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(inputUri);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"nav\"]");
```

An example bit of code that I've seen saying to use the WebBrowser control:

```
if (this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0] != null)
_htmlAgilityPackDocument.LoadHtml(this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0].OuterHtml);
```

How can I grab the page once AJAX has been loaded?

Comment: You can use Selenium web driver for web scrapping. HAP will only give you page source. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that using HTMLAgilityPack it is only possible to scrape content that is loaded via the html itself. Thus anything loaded via AJAX will not be visible to HTMLAgilityPack.

Perhaps the easiest option -where feasible- is to use a browser based tool such as Firebug to determine the source of the data loaded by AJAX. Then manipulate the source data directly. An added advantage of this might be the ability to scrape a larger dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled all day to get this right so here is a FedEx tracking example of what the accepted answer is referring to (I think):

```
        Dim body As String
        body = "data={""TrackPackagesRequest"":{""appType"":""WTRK"",""appDeviceType"":""DESKTOP"",""supportHTML"":true,""supportCurrentLocation"":true,""uniqueKey"":"""",""processingParameters"":{},""trackingInfoList"":[{""trackNumberInfo"":{""trackingNumber"":" & Chr(34) & "YOUR TRACKING NUMBER HERE" & Chr(34) & ",""trackingQualifier"":"""",""trackingCarrier"":""""}}]}}"
        body = body & "&action=trackpackages&locale=en_US&version=1&format=json"

        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open("POST", "https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track", False)
            .setRequestHeader("Referer", "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=YOUR TRACKING NUMBER HERE")
            .setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
            .setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
            .setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
            .send(body)
            Dim Reply = .responseText
        End With
```

Alternatively have you considered building a browser into your application using Cefsharp.net and then using Dev Tools through the .net interface?

You may have noticed that even dynamically AJAX/JS generated HTML can be found using e.g. Inspect Element option in Firefox. So that code is sitting on your computer even if you can't scrape it using traditional HTML scraping methods.

Another option to consider.

https://cefsharp.github.io/