# HTMLagilitypack can't parse content

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, geckofx

I use for my C# project Geckofx and Htmlagilitypack to parse some websites (e.g. Xing, LinkedIn). 
Since LinkedIn has updated their webpages, it is not possible to parse infos. Because the informations are being loaded with ajax after the page loaded. That's why, the informations, which i need is not prepare in source code and this disables HtmlAgilityPack to get information.

For example see the page: https://www.linkedin.com/in/johntroch/

How can i parse the content?

Comment: what you want to fetch from the link of linkedin you mentioned ?

Comment: For example his name, position and city, but if you view the source code, there is absolutly no information.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with a manual controlling:

```
                while (!getSource().Contains("any text");)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
```

getSource() is another method which gives me the source code of page. I make a check til i get my text. Then i get all the source code with dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing earlier this week. Unfortunately, if the answer from this similar question still applies, it is not possible to do using only HTMLAgilityPack :(

[HTMLAgilityPack load AJAX content for scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907125/htmlagilitypack-load-ajax-content-for-scraping)

Comment: It's no problem for me, what should i use instead of HTMLAgilityPack?

Comment: You could try using the firebug add on within Firefox. This I believe uses the DOM and not just the Markup (unlike HTMLAgilityPack). It would pay to get the div by class where possible instead of the standard XPATH. Unless you don't mind updating the code if the site structure changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `HAP` but you can do it with the help of Selenium Web Driver/Web Browser control or PhantomJS for headless browser. Here is the sample of using PhantomJS driver.

```
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/in/johntroch/");
var backpack = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'profile-overview')]"));
```

The above piece of code will get you this:

[image: output of nodes fetched]

Here is the [Link](https://learn2automate.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/headless-automation-using-c-phantomjs-and-nunit/) of how you can use PhantomJS and for selenium [Visit this](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/)